# replace content of a column by the content of a variable

Tags: bash, awk, grep

my final goal is to replace, for each line of the GQPDOMB_impute_copie.vcf file, the info column (column 8 of the GQPDOMB_impute_copie.vcf file) by the contents of columns 2 and 3 of the formatting.txt file:

That's my idea:

```
For each line of the GQPDOMB_impute_copie.vcf file
do 
    the variable rs retrieves the rsID of the current line in column 3 of the GQPDOMB_impute_copie.vcf file
    The variable VAR1 searches for the content of the variable rs in the formatting.txt file for each line
    if the variable is not empty (the content of rs for this line has been found in the formatting.txt file)
    so
        the ra variable recovers the contents of columns 2 and 3 of the formatting.txt file
        The content of column 8 of the current row is replaced by the content of the variable ra (which contains the information contained in columns 2 and 3 of formatting.txt)
    fi
done
```

GQPDOMB_impute_copie.vcf :

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.3
1   783071  rs142849724 C   T   .   PASS    TYPED;RefPanelAF=0.018571;AN=80;AC=5;INFO=1 GT  0|0 0|0 1|0 0|0 1|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0
1   783186  rs141989890 G   C   .   PASS    RefPanelAF=0.000323375;AN=80;AC=0;INFO=1    GT  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
1   783632  rs193023236 G   A   .   PASS    RefPanelAF=0.00040037;AN=80;AC=0;INFO=1 GT  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
```

formating.txt :

```
rs142849724;ENSG00000228794;ENST00000624927|ENST00000623808|ENST00000445118|ENST00000448975|ENST00000610067|ENST00000608189|ENST00000609139|ENST00000449005|ENST00000416570|ENST00000623070|ENST00000609009|ENST00000622921
rs141989890;ENSG00000228794;ENST00000624927|ENST00000623808|ENST00000445118|ENST00000448975|ENST00000610067|ENST00000608189|ENST00000609139|ENST00000449005|ENST00000416570|ENST00000623070|ENST00000609009|ENST00000622921
rs193023236;ENSG00000228794;ENST00000624927|ENST00000623808|ENST00000445118|ENST00000448975|ENST00000610067|ENST00000608189|ENST00000609139|ENST00000449005|ENST00000416570|ENST00000623070|ENST00000609009|ENST00000622921
```

After a lot of research on the internet, here is the code I can offer you:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
   rs=$(awk -F '\t' '{print $3}' GQPDOMB_impute_copie.vcf)     #recovery rsID
   VAR1=$(grep "${rs}" formating.txt)      #we check if the rsID of the current line is found in the file formatting.txt
   if [ -n "$VAR1" ] ;     #if the rsID of the current line has been found
   then
       ra=$(grep "${rs}" formating.txt | awk -F ';' '{print $2,";",$3}')   #recovery of the contents of columns 2 and 3 of the formating.txt file in the same vaiable  
       awk -F '\t' -v t="\"$ra\"" '{$8=t; print }' OFS='\t' GQPDOMB_impute_copie.vcf   #replace the content of the column 8 (info) with the content of the prévious var
   fi
done < GQPDOMB_impute_copie.vcf
```

However, I think the program does not read the vcf file line by line and does not succeed in creating the variable VAR1. Here is the error that was returned to me:

```
./script-info.sh: line 16: /usr/bin/grep: Argument list too long
./script-info.sh: line 16: /usr/bin/grep: Argument list too long
./script-info.sh: line 16: /usr/bin/grep: Argument list too long
```

How to succeed in creating this script and if possible as efficiently as possible?

I thank you for that.

***Edit*** : As you wish, here is how I would like to recover my output file :

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.3
1   783071  rs142849724 C   T   .   PASS    ENSG00000228794;ENST00000624927|ENST00000623808|ENST00000445118|ENST00000448975|ENST00000610067|ENST00000608189|ENST00000609139|ENST00000449005|ENST00000416570|ENST00000623070|ENST00000609009|ENST00000622921
 GT  0|0 0|0 1|0 0|0 1|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0
1   783186  rs141989890 G   C   .   PASS    ENSG00000228794;ENST00000624927|ENST00000623808|ENST00000445118|ENST00000448975|ENST00000610067|ENST00000608189|ENST00000609139|ENST00000449005|ENST00000416570|ENST00000623070|ENST00000609009|ENST00000622921    GT  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
1   783632  rs193023236 G   A   .   PASS    ENSG00000228794;ENST00000624927|ENST00000623808|ENST00000445118|ENST00000448975|ENST00000610067|ENST00000608189|ENST00000609139|ENST00000449005|ENST00000416570|ENST00000623070|ENST00000609009|ENST00000622921 GT  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
```

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input.

Comment: Running AWK inside a loop is expensive. AWK will loop over files for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without showing us the expected output we're guessing at what you want but maybe this is it:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN   { FS=";" }
NR==FNR { val[$1] = $2 FS $3; next }
FNR==1  { FS=OFS="\t"; $0=$0 }
!/^#/   { $8 = ($3 in val ? val[$3] : $8) }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk formatting.txt GQPDOMB_impute_copie.vcf
##fileformat=VCFv4.3
1       783071  rs142849724     C       T       .       PASS    ENSG00000228794;ENST00000624927|ENST00000623808|ENST00000445118|ENST00000448975|ENST00000610067|ENST00000608189|ENST00000609139|ENST00000449005|ENST00000416570|ENST00000623070|ENST00000609009|ENST00000622921 GT      0|0     0|0     1|0     0|0     1|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|1     0|0     0|00|0      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|00|0      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|1     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|1     0|0     0|0     0|0
1       783186  rs141989890     G       C       .       PASS    ENSG00000228794;ENST00000624927|ENST00000623808|ENST00000445118|ENST00000448975|ENST00000610067|ENST00000608189|ENST00000609139|ENST00000449005|ENST00000416570|ENST00000623070|ENST00000609009|ENST00000622921 GT      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|00|0      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|00|0      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
1       783632  rs193023236     G       A       .       PASS    ENSG00000228794;ENST00000624927|ENST00000623808|ENST00000445118|ENST00000448975|ENST00000610067|ENST00000608189|ENST00000609139|ENST00000449005|ENST00000416570|ENST00000623070|ENST00000609009|ENST00000622921 GT      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|00|0      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|00|0      0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton. I thank you for your precious help and I thank you very much because it has been many of you that have been of great help to me! I would like to ask you one last question, in the code I proposed, is this the right solution to get the content of a command in a variable and is this the right way to use this variable in a grep? Thank you very much!

Comment: @AmandineLecerfDefer you're welcome. It's very rare for storing multi-line text in a variable to be the right way to do anything and idk how you're planning to use such a variable with grep (plus you're already using awk so it's hard to imagine why you'd want to also use grep) so I think the answers to your questions would have to be - don't do that. If you have something specific you're trying to achieve that you think saving multi-,line output from awk in a variable to then pass to grep would be the best approach for then ask a new question to get help.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations